# Convergence on a metric space with two equivalent metrics

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification

> Let $X$ be a set. Let $d$ and $d'$ be equivalent metrics on $X$. Show that a sequence $x_n \in X$ converges in $(X,d)$ iff $x_n$ converges in $(X,d')$.

$" \Longrightarrow"$ Assume that $x_n \to x$ in $(X,d)$. Since $d$ and $d'$ are equivalent we have that $id : (X,d) \to (X,d')$ is a homeomorphism and thus continuous. From continuity we have that since $x_n \to x$, then $id(x_n) \to id(x)$

$" \Longleftarrow"$ Assume that $x_n \to x$ in $(X,d')$. Since $id : (X,d) \to (X,d')$ is a homeomoprhism it also has a continuous inverse call it $g :(X,d') \to (X,d)$. Now since $x_n \to x$ by the continuity of $g$ we have that $g(x_n) \to g(x)$.

I'm not sure this is correct. I would appreciate if someone could give me some advice on how to improve this?

Comment: You only have to prove on direction. The other follows from the first  by switching the two.

Comment: Your proof is, however, correct. I like using that $id$ is continuous

Answer (score 1):

$d$ and $d'$ generate the same topology on $X$ so have the same convergent sequences in $X$ by definition. You don't have to mention homeomorphisms.

Note that $x_n \to x$ iff $$\forall O \in \mathcal{T}: (x \in O) \implies (\exists N \in \Bbb N: \forall n \ge N: x_n \in O)$$

so convergence only depends on the open sets in a topology. And $d$ and $d'$ have the *same* open sets by definition of equivalent topologies.

Comment: Technically, convergence is defined in metric spaces in terms of the metric and balls, not in terms of general open sets. And convergence doesn’t make sense in general topology (where you get stuck with things like “nets.”) Plus, I liked using the homomorphism. (Technically, OP only needed that $id$ is continuous....)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews convergence *is* defined in all topological spaces (exactly as above) and it's a special case of net convergence. "doesn't make sense" is not true, many topological spaces are even sequential.

Comment: Maybe I’m misremembering, I thought nets were used because convergence is not unique in general topology.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews net convergence need also not be unique in general. It's only that in a general space closed and sequentially closed need not be the same. Likewise with continuity and sequential continuity. To get such an equivalence we need nets.